# Why does scipy.optimize.curve_fit not fit to the data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I've been trying to fit an exponential to some data for a while using scipy.optimize.curve_fit but i'm having real difficulty. I really can't see any reason why this wouldn't work but it just produces a strait line, no idea why!

Any help would be much appreciated

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

def func(x,a,b,c):
   return a*numpy.exp(-b*x)-c


yData = numpy.load('yData.npy')
xData = numpy.load('xData.npy')

trialX = numpy.linspace(xData[0],xData[-1],1000)

# Fit a polynomial 
fitted = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, 10)[::-1]
y = numpy.zeros(len(trailX))
for i in range(len(fitted)):
   y += fitted[i]*trialX**i

# Fit an exponential
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData)
yEXP = func(trialX, *popt)

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.plot(xData, yData, label='Data', marker='o')
pyplot.plot(trialX, yEXP, 'r-',ls='--', label="Exp Fit")
pyplot.plot(trialX,   y, label = '10 Deg Poly')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

```
xData = [1e-06, 2e-06, 3e-06, 4e-06,
5e-06, 6e-06, 7e-06, 8e-06,
9e-06, 1e-05, 2e-05, 3e-05,
4e-05, 5e-05, 6e-05, 7e-05,
8e-05, 9e-05, 0.0001, 0.0002,
0.0003, 0.0004, 0.0005, 0.0006,
0.0007, 0.0008, 0.0009, 0.001,
0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005,
0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01]

yData = 
[6.37420666067e-09, 1.13082012115e-08,
1.52835756975e-08, 2.19214493931e-08, 2.71258852882e-08, 3.38556130078e-08, 3.55765277358e-08,
4.13818145846e-08, 4.72543475372e-08, 4.85834751151e-08, 9.53876562077e-08, 1.45110636413e-07,
1.83066627931e-07, 2.10138415308e-07, 2.43503982686e-07, 2.72107045549e-07, 3.02911771395e-07,
3.26499455951e-07, 3.48319349445e-07, 5.13187669283e-07, 5.98480176303e-07, 6.57028222701e-07,
6.98347073045e-07, 7.28699930335e-07, 7.50686502279e-07, 7.7015576866e-07, 7.87147246927e-07,
7.99607141001e-07, 8.61398763228e-07, 8.84272900407e-07, 8.96463883243e-07, 9.04105135329e-07,
9.08443443149e-07, 9.12391264185e-07, 9.150842683e-07, 9.16878548643e-07, 9.18389990067e-07]
```

Comment: I get multiple errors when I try to run your code- first, `trialX` is misspelled, and then I get an `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes` error. Are you sure this is your exact code?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: to deal with the operands issue, make sure `xData` and `yData` are both `ndarray`s.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Numerical algorithms tend to work better when not fed extremely small (or large) numbers.

In this case, the graph shows your data has extremely small x and y values. If you scale them, the fit is remarkable better:

```
xData = np.load('xData.npy')*10**5
yData = np.load('yData.npy')*10**5
```

---

```
from __future__ import division

import os
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/tmp'))

import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x,a,b,c):
   return a*np.exp(-b*x)-c


xData = np.load('xData.npy')*10**5
yData = np.load('yData.npy')*10**5

print(xData.min(), xData.max())
print(yData.min(), yData.max())

trialX = np.linspace(xData[0], xData[-1], 1000)

# Fit a polynomial 
fitted = np.polyfit(xData, yData, 10)[::-1]
y = np.zeros(len(trialX))
for i in range(len(fitted)):
   y += fitted[i]*trialX**i

# Fit an exponential
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, xData, yData)
print(popt)
yEXP = func(trialX, *popt)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xData, yData, label='Data', marker='o')
plt.plot(trialX, yEXP, 'r-',ls='--', label="Exp Fit")
plt.plot(trialX, y, label = '10 Deg Poly')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that after rescaling `xData` and `yData`, the parameters returned by `curve_fit` must also be rescaled. In this case, `a`, `b` and `c` each must be divided by 10**5 to obtain fitted parameters for the original data.

---

One objection you might have to the above is that the scaling has to be chosen rather "carefully". (Read: Not every reasonable choice of scale works!)

You can improve the robustness of `curve_fit` by providing a reasonable initial guess for the parameters. Usually you have some *a priori* knowledge about the data which can motivate ballpark / back-of-the envelope type guesses for reasonable parameter values.

For example, calling `curve_fit` with

```
guess = (-1, 0.1, 0)
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, xData, yData, guess)
```

helps improve the range of scales on which `curve_fit` succeeds in this case.

Comment: That's much better! is there a reason that it doesn't like small numbers?

Comment: I haven't studied `curve_fit's` algorithm closely enough to tell you exactly why. But in general, these algorithms need to test a guess for the parameter values, then tweak the guess. The size of initial tweak may work well if the data have magnitude around 1, but may overshoot the correct answer completely if the data has magnitude around 10**-6.

Comment: @unutbu You were right about the initial guess being around 1.
From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit

`p0 : None, scalar, or M-length sequence
Initial guess for the parameters. If None, then the initial values will all be 1 (if the number of parameters for the function can be determined using introspection, otherwise a ValueError is raised).`

Where `scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, **kw)[source]`

Answer (score 26):

A (slight) improvement to this solution, not accounting for a priori knowledge of the data might be the following: Take the inverse-mean of the data set and use that as the "scale factor" to be passed to the underlying leastsq() called by curve_fit(). This allows the fitter to work and returns the parameters on the original scale of the data.

The relevant line is:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData)
```

which becomes:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData,
    diag=(1./xData.mean(),1./yData.mean()) )
```

Here is the full example which produces this image:

[image: curve_fit without manually rescaling the data or results]

```python
from __future__ import division
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

def func(x,a,b,c):
   return a*numpy.exp(-b*x)-c


xData = numpy.array([1e-06, 2e-06, 3e-06, 4e-06, 5e-06, 6e-06,
7e-06, 8e-06, 9e-06, 1e-05, 2e-05, 3e-05, 4e-05, 5e-05, 6e-05,
7e-05, 8e-05, 9e-05, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0004, 0.0005,
0.0006, 0.0007, 0.0008, 0.0009, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005
, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01])

yData = numpy.array([6.37420666067e-09, 1.13082012115e-08,
1.52835756975e-08, 2.19214493931e-08, 2.71258852882e-08,
3.38556130078e-08, 3.55765277358e-08, 4.13818145846e-08,
4.72543475372e-08, 4.85834751151e-08, 9.53876562077e-08,
1.45110636413e-07, 1.83066627931e-07, 2.10138415308e-07,
2.43503982686e-07, 2.72107045549e-07, 3.02911771395e-07,
3.26499455951e-07, 3.48319349445e-07, 5.13187669283e-07,
5.98480176303e-07, 6.57028222701e-07, 6.98347073045e-07,
7.28699930335e-07, 7.50686502279e-07, 7.7015576866e-07,
7.87147246927e-07, 7.99607141001e-07, 8.61398763228e-07,
8.84272900407e-07, 8.96463883243e-07, 9.04105135329e-07,
9.08443443149e-07, 9.12391264185e-07, 9.150842683e-07,
9.16878548643e-07, 9.18389990067e-07])

trialX = numpy.linspace(xData[0],xData[-1],1000)

# Fit a polynomial
fitted = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, 10)[::-1]
y = numpy.zeros(len(trialX))
for i in range(len(fitted)):
   y += fitted[i]*trialX**i

# Fit an exponential
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData,
    diag=(1./xData.mean(),1./yData.mean()) )
yEXP = func(trialX, *popt)

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.plot(xData, yData, label='Data', marker='o')
pyplot.plot(trialX, yEXP, 'r-',ls='--', label="Exp Fit")
pyplot.plot(trialX,   y, label = '10 Deg Poly')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Very nice addition to the answer! A priori knowledge may pretty much always be available when doing interactive analysis, it is not always the case with automated setups.

Answer (score -5):

the model `a*exp(-b*x)+c` fit well the data, but I suggest a little modification:
use this instead

`a*x*exp(-b*x)+c`

good luck