# curve_fit doesn't work properly with 4 parameters

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

Running the following code,

```
x = np.array([50.849937, 53.849937, 56.849937, 59.849937, 62.849937, 65.849937, 68.849937, 71.849937, 74.849937, 77.849937, 80.849937, 83.849937, 86.849937, 89.849937, 92.849937])
y = np.array([410.67800, 402.63800, 402.63800, 386.55800, 330.27600, 217.71400, 72.98990, 16.70860, 8.66833, 40.82920, 241.83400, 386.55800, 394.59800, 394.59800, 402.63800])
def f(om, a, i , c):
       return a - i*np.exp(- c* (om-74.)**2)
par, cov = curve_fit(f, x, y)
stdev = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov) )
```

produces this Graph,

[image]

With the following parameters and standard deviation:

```
par =   [ 4.09652163e+02, 4.33961227e+02, 1.58719772e-02]
stdev = [ 1.46309578e+01, 2.44878171e+01, 2.40474753e-03]
```

However, when trying to fit this data to the following function:

```
def f(om, a, i , c, omo):
       return a - i*np.exp(- c* (om-omo)**2)
```

It doesn't work, it produces a standard deviation of

```
stdev = [inf, inf, inf, inf, inf]
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it isn't converging (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624070/why-does-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-not-fit-to-the-data) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420792/exponential-curve-fitting-in-scipy?rq=1)). Try adding an initial condition,

```
par, cov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[1.,1.,1.,74.])
```

which results in the

```
par = [ 4.11892318e+02, 4.36953868e+02, 1.55741131e-02, 7.32560690e+01])
stdev = [ 1.17579445e+01, 1.94401006e+01, 1.86709423e-03, 2.62952690e-01]
```

Comment: had to set all condition:
 'startfirst = [86.5, -438., -411., 73.5]', didn't work with just one, but thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the initial condition from data:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pylab as pl

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.array([50.849937, 53.849937, 56.849937, 59.849937, 62.849937, 65.849937, 68.849937, 71.849937, 74.849937, 77.849937, 80.849937, 83.849937, 86.849937, 89.849937, 92.849937])
y = np.array([410.67800, 402.63800, 402.63800, 386.55800, 330.27600, 217.71400, 72.98990, 16.70860, 8.66833, 40.82920, 241.83400, 386.55800, 394.59800, 394.59800, 402.63800])

def f(om, a, i , c, omo):
       return a - i*np.exp(- c* (om-omo)**2)

par, cov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[y.max(), y.ptp(), 1, x[np.argmin(y)]])
stdev = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov) )

pl.plot(x, y, "o")
x2 = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
pl.plot(x2, f(x2, *par))
```