# scipy.optimize.curvefit fails when using bounds

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to fit a set of data with a function (see the example below) using `scipy.optimize.curvefit`,
but when I use bounds ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)) the fit fails and I simply get 
the initial guess parameters as output.
As soon as I substitute `-np.inf` ad `np.inf` as bounds for the second parameter 
(`dt` in the function), the fit works.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

#Generate data
crc=np.array([-1.4e-14, 7.3e-14, 1.9e-13, 3.9e-13, 6.e-13, 8.0e-13, 9.2e-13, 9.9e-13, 
              1.e-12, 1.e-12, 1.e-12, 1.0e-12, 1.1e-12, 1.1e-12, 1.1e-12, 1.0e-12, 1.1e-12])
time=np.array([0., 368., 648., 960., 1520.,1864., 2248., 2655., 3031., 
                3384., 3688., 4048., 4680., 5343., 6055.,  6928.,  8120.])

#Define the function for the fit
def testcurve(x, Dp, dt):
    k = -Dp*(x+dt)*2e11
    curve = 1e-12 * (1+2*(-np.exp(k) + np.exp(4*k) - np.exp(9*k) + np.exp(16*k)))
    curve[0]= 0
    return curve

#Set fit bounds 
dtmax=time[2]
param_bounds = ((-np.inf, -dtmax),(np.inf, dtmax))

#Perform fit
(par, par_cov) = opt.curve_fit(testcurve, time, crc, p0 = (5e-15, 0), bounds = param_bounds)

#Print and plot output
print(par)       
plt.plot(time, crc, 'o')
plt.plot(time, testcurve(time, par[0], par[1]), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What are your bounds when not inf?

Comment: They're the ones in the example, +/- `time[2]`, i.e. `-648.` and `648.`
But I also tried manually entering different values, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem as well, without bounds, all my fits fail  (with curve_fit, least_squares, and even minimize and a directly defined loss function), but with bounds, they all fail.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same behavior today in a different fitting problem. After some searching online, I found this link quite helpful: [Why does scipy.optimize.curve_fit not fit to the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624070/why-does-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-not-fit-to-the-data)

The short answer is that: using extremely small (or large) numbers in numerical fitting is not robust and scale them leads to a much better fitting.

---

In your case, both `crc` and `Dp` are extremely small numbers which could be scaled up. You could play with the scale factors and within certain range the fitting looks quite robust. Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

#Generate data
crc=np.array([-1.4e-14, 7.3e-14, 1.9e-13, 3.9e-13, 6.e-13, 8.0e-13, 9.2e-13, 9.9e-13, 
              1.e-12, 1.e-12, 1.e-12, 1.0e-12, 1.1e-12, 1.1e-12, 1.1e-12, 1.0e-12, 1.1e-12])
time=np.array([0., 368., 648., 960., 1520.,1864., 2248., 2655., 3031., 
                3384., 3688., 4048., 4680., 5343., 6055.,  6928.,  8120.])

# add scale factors to the data as well as the fitting parameter
scale_factor_1 = 1e12 # 1./np.mean(crc) also works if you don't want to set the scale factor manually
scale_factor_2 = 1./2e11

#Define the function for the fit
def testcurve(x, Dp, dt):
    k = -Dp*(x+dt)*2e11 * scale_factor_2
    curve = 1e-12 * (1+2*(-np.exp(k) + np.exp(4*k) - np.exp(9*k) + np.exp(16*k))) * scale_factor_1
    curve[0]= 0
    return curve

#Set fit bounds 
dtmax=time[2]
param_bounds = ((-np.inf, -dtmax),(np.inf, dtmax))

#Perform fit
(par, par_cov) = opt.curve_fit(testcurve, time, crc*scale_factor_1, p0 = (5e-15/scale_factor_2, 0), bounds = param_bounds)

#Print and plot output
print(par[0]*scale_factor_2, par[1])

plt.plot(time, crc*scale_factor_1, 'o')
plt.plot(time, testcurve(time, par[0], par[1]), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Fitting results: `[6.273102923176595e-15, -21.12202697564494]`, which gives a reasonable fitting and also is very close to the result without any bounds: `[6.27312512e-15, -2.11307470e+01]`

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't this be independent of whether there are bounds or not however? In my case, I have the same problem as the poster; without bounds I get a normal fit as expected, with bounds it fails. Do you know what it is about bounds that would make these "small number problem" suddenly show up?

Comment: Also in your solution, in `func`, `scale_factor_2` cancels out with the `2e11` and same with `scale_factor_1`. This doesn't seem right? What's supposed to be going on there?