# How to fit with scipy.curve_fit when numbers are not close to 1?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a set of x,y points in which x lies between 0 and 100e-12 while y ranges between 0 and 1e9 and want to use [scipy.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to fit a model. It fails because of the numbers. If I rescale the data so that the numbers are closer to 1 (i.e. `x*=1e10` and `y*=1e-9`), then it works. So I know where the problem is and could eventually live with this solution. But would prefer to perform the fit in the original scale.

Is it possible?

I have seen [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238290/8849755) where it is suggested to use a `diag` argument but with this I get: `least_squares() got an unexpected keyword argument 'diag'`. I guess it was from an older version. Is there an analogous for the current version?

Additional info: I am providing curve_fit with very reasonable `p0`.

Answer (score 0):

It IS possible, but in ML it is preferable to rescale when features have different ranges. Also it helps you to increase overall performance and accuracy

If you don't live other methods, you can try Log normalization. Usually it helps to solve such problems

For example here is how you do it

```
x_norm = np.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

`curve_fit` is a wrapper of a wrapper. It calls either `least_squares` or `leastsq` depending on the method chosen with the `method` keyword argument. Default should be the latter, which permits the argument `diag`. If bounds are set, the first is chosen by  default, which has no `diag` as `kwarg`.

Personally, I would always chose to scale.